# Use SSD as cache for HDD - Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, ssd, hdd

I just bought Mac Mini 2018 base configuration for use as internal server in small company. (I need MDM, CI/CD for building apps and some other stuff.). I have 128 GB SSD and 2 * 1 TB external HDD for now.

I would like to set up Time Machine for MacBooks - currently, we have only one, but soon, we will have 3-4. 1 TB should be enough for now, so I have one drive used only for them.

But I would like to setup some "cache" on SSD - the HDD is not so fast. My idea is to have like 20 GB cache on internal SSD, to fastly backup from MacBook(s) when connected to internal Wi-Fi, and then slowly write that to the external HDD. It's probably not so big deal, but sometimes, I am out of office for longer time and I would love to have it backed up as soon as possible, so I don't have to worry about it.

Is it possible somehow, or it's easier to just accept that the speed will be limited by external HDD?

Comment: The bottleneck is the WiFi-connection here (and not the HDD). It would require a 1 GBit (or faster) Ethernet network to outperform a more or less modern HDD!

Comment: I don't think so. Mac Mini is through 1 GBit ethernet, of course, but the MacBooks are connected through fast Wi-Fi. It's not 1 GBit, of course, but I can get to 400+ Mbit

Comment: Next problem: assuming you want to split the internal SSD (108 GB system & 20 GB TM cache) the internal SSD has two mutually exclusive roles: a drive (volume) which requires a backup (because it's the server's system volume) and being part of a backup drive.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Thank you anyway - I will probably just stick with the HDD only.

Comment: In a similar setup I bought 5 x 1TB 2,5" drives and attached them to the (i)Macs...because WiFi was to slow (with ~25 concurrent WiFi-networks 2.4/5 in the direct vicinity).

Comment: I've read an article 'Do-It-Yourself APFS Fusion Drive'. However I think it would bring more hassle then benefits.